# Help with some predicate Calculus arguments

Tags: predicate-logic

I just need a little help finishing off this proof, not sure where to go from here with introducing (∀x)

(∀x) F(x) ⇒ G(x), (∃x) F(x) ⊢ (∀x) G(x)

1 (1) (∀x) F(x) ⇒ G(x)  A

2 (2) (∃x) F(x)         A

3 (3) F(a) A

1 (4) F(a) ⇒ G(a)       1 ∀ E

1, 3 (5) G(a)           3, 4 MP

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can only generalize to (∃x) G(x), not (∀x) G(x). You got line 3 by existential instantiation, which means that your "a" is some specific value (one for which it holds that F(a)), and not a free variable.

Comment: You cannot prove it, because it is not *valid*.